# Plesk equivalent to linux 'ea-php'

Tags: composer-php, plesk, plesk-onyx

The title is pretty self explanatory to be honest.

On a linux server, if I want to run a command as a different php version, such as installing composer, i can run

```
 ea-php71 composer install
```

Does anyone know the equivalent to doing this in a plesk server? My current composer install is using php56.exe, but i need to install composer with php 71 on command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like

/opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php /usr/lib64/plesk-9.0/composer.phar install